# Snowflake object - include only specific keys from a deeply nested key, but automatically select all the rest without specifying them

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In a snowflake table, one column is a deeply nested OBJECT (json).

I need to create a select statement that fetches this value as is, except for one specific, deeply nested key.

In this specific key, which is assumed to be a json, I want to include only specific keys and omit all the rest.

Eventually, I need to get back the original OBJECT (json), with the specific nested key of interest containing just part of it's original keys.

Given the input object:

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": {
    "d": {
      "e": "f",
      "this-should-be-excluded": "bla",
      "g": "h"
    },
    "i": "j",
    "k": "l"
  }
}
```

The desired output object is:

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": {
    "d": {
      "e": "f",
      "g": "h"
    },
    "i": "j",
    "k": "l"
  }
}
```

How can this be achieved in a snowflake query?

Keep in mind, the only thing known to me at runtime is that from `"c"."d"` I want to select only `"e"` and `"g"`.

I know nothing about the key `"c"."this-should-be-excluded"` and other keys like `"a"` or `"c"."i"`

Performance is an issue for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript UDF makes it easy to delete a nested JSON object by path (dotted notation):

```
create or replace function DELETE_OBJECT_BY_PATH(OBJECT object, PATH string)
returns object
language javascript strict immutable
as
$$
    deleteByPath(OBJECT, PATH.split("."));
    return OBJECT;
    function deleteByPath(obj, path) {
        var l = path.pop();
        delete path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] || {}, obj)[l];
    }
$$;

with T1 as
(
    select parse_json($${
  "a": "b",
  "c": {
    "d": {
      "e": "f",
      "this-should-be-excluded": "bla",
      "g": "h"
    },
    "i": "j",
    "k": "l"
  }
}$$) as OBJ
)
select delete_object_by_path(OBJ, 'c.d.this-should-be-excluded') as OBJ
from T1
;
```

| OBJ |
| --- |
| { "a": "b", "c": { "d": { "e": "f", "g": "h" }, "i": "j", "k": "l" } } |